# Scala Future for Comprehension

Tags: scala, future

I have a method that is supposed to go over a Future and return a Tuple. Here it is:

```
  private def myMethod(id: Long): Future[(Double, Double)] = {
    val result = for {
      someValue <- run { getFromDb(id).headOption }
      value     <- someValue
    } yield {
      value.valueType match {
        case ValueType.TypeA => (1.0, 1.0)
        case ValueType.TypeB => (2.0, 2.0)
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my run method:

```
  private def run[R](dbio: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[R, slick.dbio.NoStream, scala.Nothing]) = async {
    await(db.run(dbio))
  }
```

It uses the Scala Async library to time my calls to the database!

the getFromDB method is just doing a query:

```
def getFromDb(myId: Long) {
  MyTableQuery.filter(_.id === myId)
}
```

It complaints that  myMethod returns a Future[Nothing]. I do not see any problems here. Any clues as to what might not satisfy the return type that I'm looking for?

Comment: Isn't `async {await(db.run(dbio))}`  the same as just `db.run(dbio)` ?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the problem! When I have multiple calls to the database, I can time it to run sequentially using the run method!

Comment: Understood. What is the return type of `run`? Because your are flatMapping over the return value once more, suggesting that you have something like a `Future[Future[T]]` as a return value, which seems odd.

Comment: The return type of run is Future[R]

Comment: ...and `R` is thus inferred from `getFromDb`, whose definition is also missing. Please post a complete snippet.

Comment: Ok I added the method getFromDb, but that is just doing a simple query on the TableQuery type that I have defined!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simplified version which exhibits the same fault:

```
def method: Future[(Double, Double)] = {
  val result = for {
    someValue <- Future("a")
    value     <- Future("b")
  } yield {
    value match {
      case "a" => (1.0, 1.0)
      case "b" => (2.0, 2.0)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that you are capturing the return type in the `result` value, so the method has no return type. A valid form of this simplified function would be either of the following:

```
def method: Future[(Double, Double)] = {
  val result = for {
    someValue <- Future("a")
    value     <- Future("b")
  } yield {
    value match {
      case "a" => (1.0, 1.0)
      case "b" => (2.0, 2.0)
    }
  }
  result
}
```

Or:

```
def method: Future[(Double, Double)] = {
  for {
    someValue <- Future("a")
    value     <- Future("b")
  } yield {
    value match {
      case "a" => (1.0, 1.0)
      case "b" => (2.0, 2.0)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't be so stupid. For some strange reason, my IntelliJ was complaining that It sees a Future[Nothing] and all of a sudden it dissapeared and seems to be returning the proper tuple type!

Comment: Another strange thing that I noticed is that if I remove the return type from my method, my IntelliJ complains saying that it sees a Future[Nothing] as the result! So I have to keep the return type intact for it to work!

Comment: "my IntelliJ was complaining" IDEA error detection in Scala just isn't reliable. You need to check whether it actually compiles.